# How can I insert a variable in a string in .js, coming from a ruby example

Tags: javascript, ruby

In ruby you can insert variables into a string like this:

```
x = "sake"
puts "I like #{x}"
$"I like sake"
```

For example:

```
def what_i_like(word)
  "I like #{word}"
end
```

Is there a similar way to do this in javascript?

What I'm doing now is this:

```
x = "sake"
"I like" + x + ". "
```

Comment: I think your question is exactly the same as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-printf-string-format

Comment: You need to declare variable var v = "sake" with a word reserved 'var', do you wrote this?

Comment: You should declare your variables with 'var', otherwise you pollute the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is supported in vanilla Javascript in the console.log function. The format would work as follows:

```
console.log('Hey %s', 'cat');
```

which results in

`"Hey cat"`

If you happen to be using Node.js, this functionality is supported out of box with the util.format(...) function, working pretty much the same way except that it just returns a string.

%s = string

%d = integer or float

%j = stringifyable object

Imo this approach might be slightly more idiomatic javascript than using an external library that simulates a ruby or C syntax, IF you are already using Node.js in some capacity.

https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format